# CSS Grid - using grid-template-columns without creating empty div's

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to create a screen where there is only one `div`, who is 
centered and takes 33% of the screen in size. Both right and left to it is empty. 
What I do is :

```
.loginScreenContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

And create 3 elements which two are empty.

```
 <div className='loginScreenContainer'>
      <div>Empty</div>
      <div>Actual Content</div>
      <div>Empty</div>
 </div>
```

It feels awkward.
Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `grid-column: 2` to your content. Then the content will be in the correct column.

```css
.loginScreenContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.content {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class='loginScreenContainer'>
  <div class="content">Actual Content</div>
</div>
```

Here's a great guide for a lot of css-grid properties: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Thank u. Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use grid. You can do this using width and margin.

HTML

```
<div class='loginScreenContainer'>
      <div>Actual Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.loginScreenContainer {
    width: 33%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Check this out
https://jsfiddle.net/tb9dqz07/1/